# Can I get the product of my CASE Statement?

Tags: sql-server

I have to multiply the result of my CASE statement.
What is the desired way to do it?

My CASE Statement is:

```
CASE
   WHEN dbo.ItemSpecs.ConfigProptext LIKE 'Coco Chair%' THEN (CEILING(dbo.WorkOrderDetails.QtyOrdered / 4)) 
   WHEN dbo.ItemSpecs.ConfigProptext LIKE 'Cruise Bar%' THEN (CEILING(dbo.WorkOrderDetails.QtyOrdered / 4)) 
   ELSE dbo.WorkOrderDetails.QtyOrdered 
END AS NumberofCartons
```

The result of all this query should be multiplied by 0.25 and that should be create new column called Goods Cubic Column.

Can you please advice?

Comment: I like to put the short statements beforehand, so `0.25 * CASE ... END` ? But if you want to round down, and your `CASE` returns an integer, then instead do `CASE ... END / 4` to leverage implicit casting. If you wanna round up without relying on the numeric data type (i.e. avoid adding 0.9999 which varies on data type precision), do `-CONVERT(INT, -0.25 * CASE ... END)` because rounding down a negative number, then negating it is the same as rounding up a positive number.

Comment: What you have now is fine, or see the above comment.

Comment: Also use square brackets to give column aliases with spaces (I don't like the `SELECT ... AS 'name'` syntax), do `SELECT [Goods Cubic Column] = ...`

Comment: `case expression` (an `expression` evaluates to a single value) whereas a `statement` is a larger more complex item  e.g. `update statement`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Moving the CASE expression to a CROSS APPLY in the from clause, will make its alias avail to reference in the SELECT list.
Something like the following should do what you're looking for...

```
SELECT 
    nc.NumberofCartons,
    Goods_Cubic_Column = nc.NumberofCartons * 0.25
FROM
    dbo.ItemSpecs isp
    JOIN dbo.WorkOrderDetails wod
        ON isp.??? = wod.???
    CROSS APPLY ( VALUES (
                        CASE
                           WHEN isp.ConfigProptext LIKE 'Coco Chair%' THEN (CEILING(wod.QtyOrdered / 4)) 
                           WHEN isp.ConfigProptext LIKE 'Cruise Bar%' THEN (CEILING(wod.QtyOrdered / 4)) 
                           ELSE wod.QtyOrdered 
                        END )
                    ) nc (NumberofCartons);
```